# unable to launch chromium browser,is there any solution?

Tags: ubuntu, chromium

i have installed gnome-3-34-1804
but when i tried to launch chromium it came up with an error

**ERROR: not connected to the gnome-3-28-1804 content interface.**

though i have gnome-3-34-1804

```
snap connections snap-store

content[gnome-3-34-1804]  snap-store:gnome-3-34-1804
```

why is it asking for gnome-3-28-1804?
then i tried

```
snap connect chromium:gnome-3-34-1804 gnome-3-34-1804:gnome-3-34-1804
```

and again error

**snap "chromium" has no plug named "gnome-3-34-1804"**

Comment: Did you ever solve it?

Answer (score 1):

```sh
snap remove gnome-3-28-1804
snap install gnome-3-28-1804
```

Fixed it for me. I didn't have to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

once you remove and reboot your PC it will worked correctly

Answer (score 0):

I am getting a similar issue with a different package.
Running

```
snap install gnome-3-28-1804
```

is how I started to solve my issue. But, I got the following error(s):

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/0': Permission denied
ERROR: You need to connect this snap to the wine platform snap.

You can do this with those commands:
snap install wine-platform-6-stable
snap connect {application}:wine-6-stable wine-platform-6-stable
```

```
ERROR: You need to connect this snap to the wine runtime snap.

You can do this with those commands:
snap install wine-platform-runtime
snap connect {application}:wine-runtime wine-platform-runtime
```

is the suggested fix by the application I needed to run. Hope it helps.